# Getting first image from RSS feed (PHP CURL)

Tags: php, curl

Below code works to pull data from an RSS feed using PHP CURL, however I can't seem to figure out how to get the image URL from the description variable. I just need the first image.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::description() in      /home/feedolu/public_html/index.php on line 26 

    Function feedMe($feed) {
// Use cURL to fetch text
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $feed);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
$rss = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Manipulate string into object
$rss = simplexml_load_string($rss);

$siteTitle = $rss->channel->title;
echo "<h1>".$siteTitle."</h1>";
echo "<hr />";

$cnt = count($rss->channel->item);

for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
{
    $url = $rss->channel->item[$i]->link;
    $title = $rss->channel->item[$i]->title;
    $desc = $rss->channel->item[$i]->description;
    $image = $rss->channel->item[$i]->description('img', 0);
    echo '<h3><a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a></h3>'.$desc.'';
    echo $image;
}
}

 feedMe("localhost/feed/");
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is associated with this link, obviously:

```
$image = $rss->channel->item[$i]->description('img', 0);
```

In the context of a `SimpleXML` class, the `description` is a property, and not a function. Using the `xpath()` function to find all `<img />`'s makes quick work of the problem.

So, based on your code, here is how I would get the value that you are looking for (even though I don't think your implementation is the best):

```
$images = $rss->channel->item[$i]->description->xpath('img');
if (count($images) > 0) {
    $image = $images['src'];
}
```

Comment: I wasn't thinking before. The TAG I need to extract the image from is the content. Which of course is content:encode. This doesn't work because of the ":".                                            for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
 {
  $url = $rss->channel->item[$i]->link;
  $title = $rss->channel->item[$i]->title;
  $desc = $rss->channel->item[$i]->description;
  $content = $rss->channel->item[$i]->content:encoded;
  $images = $rss->channel->item[$i]->content->xpath('img');
  if (count($images) > 0) {
      $image = $images['src'];
  }
    
   }

Comment: Okay I HAVE to be close now with the content:encode thingie  for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
 {
  $url = $rss->channel->item[$i]->link;
  $title = $rss->channel->item[$i]->title;
  $desc = $rss->channel->item[$i]->description;
  $content = $rss->channel->item[$i]->xpath('content:encoded');
  $images = $rss->channel->item[$i]->content->xpath('img');
  if (count($images) > 0) {
      $image = $images['src'];
  }
    echo '<h3><a href="'.$url.'">'.$title.'</a></h3>'.$desc.'';
    echo $image;
    echo $content;
   }
 }

Answer (score 0):

The solution on this page worked for me:-

[How to get first image from a tumlbr rss feed in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28862873/how-to-get-first-image-from-a-tumlbr-rss-feed-in-php)

```
$image = '';
if (preg_match('/src="(.*?)"/', $rss->channel->item[$i]->description, $matches)) {
    $image = $matches[1];
}
```