# How to get first image from a tumlbr rss feed in PHP

Tags: php, xml, xpath, rss, tumblr

0Here is the relevant part of my rss feed:

```
    <channel>
        <description></description>
        <title>Untitled</title>
        <generator>Tumblr (3.0; @xxx)</generator>
        <link>http://xxx.tumblr.com/</link> 
        <item>
            <title>Title</title>
            <description>&lt;figure&gt;&lt;img src="https://31.media.tumblr.com/c78c7t3abd23423549d3bb0f705/tumblr_inline_nkp9z234d0uj.jpg"/&gt;&lt;/figure&gt;</description>
            <link>http://xxx.tumblr.com/post/99569244093</link>
            <guid>http://xxx.tumblr.com/post/99569244093</guid>
            <pubDate>Thu, 09 Oct 2014 11:19:33 -0400</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
```

Using the answer from other questions on here I tried this:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://xxx.tumblr.com/rss"); 
$feed = new SimpleXmlElement($content); 
$imgs = $feed->channel->item[0]->description->xpath('//img');
    foreach($imgs as $image) {
            echo (string)$image['src'];     
};
```

This is returning an empty array for `$imgs`

Does it have something to do with the tags being `&lt; &gt;` etc?

and if so what can I do?

Comment: There are no `img` elements in the XML you've posted.  `&lt;img src="..."/&gt;` does not count.

Comment: That's what I thought might be the problem.. :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from the description, which seems to include a HTML image tag for the image, by using a simple regular expression with `preg_match`:

```
$content = file_get_contents("http://xxx.tumblr.com/rss");
$feed    = new SimpleXmlElement($content);
$img     = (string)$feed->channel->item[0]->description;

if (preg_match('/src="(.*?)"/', $img, $matches)) {
    $src = $matches[1];
    echo "src = $src", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:

```
src = http://40.media.tumblr.com/58d24c3009638514325b113859ba369f/tumblr_nk0mwfhKXU1sl87kjo1_500.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured regex was the best way to go... but it still scares me xD

Answer (score 1):

Before you can use `xapth()` on the description, you need to create a new XML document out of it:

```
$url  = "http://xxx.tumblr.com/rss";
$desc = simplexml_load_file($url)->xpath('//item/description[1]')[0];
$src  = simplexml_load_string("<x>$desc</x>")->xpath('//img/@src')[0];

echo $src;
```

Output:

```
http://40.media.tumblr.com/58d24c3009638514325b113859ba369f/tumblr_nk0mwfhKXU1sl87kjo1_500.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can use this approach - as already mentioned by kjhughes as comment, your input XML does not contain any `img` element. But it's possible to retrieve the image source using XPath substring-functions:

```
substring-before(substring-after(substring-after(//item/description[contains(.,'img')],
'src='),'"'),'"')
```

Result:

```
https://31.media.tumblr.com/c78c7t3abd23423549d3bb0f705/tumblr_inline_nkp9z234d0uj.jpg
```